# https post message fail, where is server log?

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, ssl

I am receiving an error when sending a https post message to my server and I am looking to get more information.

I am looking for ssl error log in apache but I cannot find it.  I have looked in `/usr/local/apache/logs/secure` but I don't see the proper error.

Should I be looking in a different place?

UPDATE:
The connection is timing out or getting lost when I use https and I am trying to figure out why.  When I use http it has no problems working.

Comment: It's most likely timing out because it can't even connect to the web server. For what it's worth, the log file location for SSL errors should be in a .conf file for the server.

Comment: I can connect via http fine but when I switch to https I receive the error.  I can use https for the normal website but not with my special post message.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your installation of Apache, you'll want to look for the ErrorLog directive that is set for the SSL part of your site.  This might be someplace like /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf or it might be in a VirtualHost container for port 443 in one of the config files.  Once you've found the ErrorLog directive, see if you see an LogLevel directive around it or in the same scope and either change it to debug or add your own LogLevel directive set to debug. Then restart Apache and now you should get additional error reporting on SSL in the log file referenced by the ErrorLog directive.  Of course, as Randolph mentioned, this all depends on if you don't have a firewall blocking the request.

Since you mention that you can make normal HTTPS requests fine (GET) but not your POST request, I think you should also check if you have mod_security running in Apache and try to rule out it being a problem with that.

This link will help you more with the LogLevel directive.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel